# Concrete example of Oracle CONNECT_BY_ROOT equivalent in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursive-query

I am very bad at Oracle and now I need to convert the following Oracle 11 view to Postgresql 12 view.

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW "V_DESC_VALUE_HIERARCH_FULL" ("CHILD_VALUE_ID", "PARENT_VALUE_ID", "VALUE_LEVEL") AS 
  select  DESCRIPTOR_VALUE_ID as CHILD_VALUE_ID,
        CONNECT_BY_ROOT DESCRIPTOR_VALUE_ID as PARENT_VALUE_ID,
        LEVEL as VALUE_LEVEL
   from DESCRIPTOR_VALUE
connect by prior DESCRIPTOR_VALUE_ID = PARENT_VALUE_ID;
```

All my PostgreSQL variants give absolutely different result than Oracle view. Could anyone say how to port it?

Descriptor value table is this one:

```
CREATE TABLE descriptor_value (
    descriptor_value_id bigint NOT NULL,
    descriptor_group_id bigint NOT NULL,
    full_value varchar(4000) NOT NULL,
    short_value varchar(250),
    value_code varchar(30),
    sort_order bigint NOT NULL,
    parent_value_id bigint,
    deleted smallint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    portal smallint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
) ;
```

Comment: could you share what postgres variants you have tried, and some sample source data & expected results please

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  You can also show the code that you have tried and set up a db/sql fiddle of some sort.

Comment: `parent_value_id` points to which column? What is the primary key of that table?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name descriptor_value_id is the PK.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to simulate connect_by_root, is to get the root ID in the non-recursive part and simply repeat it unaltered throughout the recursive part:

I am not sure how exactly your hierarchy is built (as the query you have is invalid and makes not sense to me).

Assuming `parent_value_id` points to `descriptor_value_id`, then you probably want something like this:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
  SELECT descriptor_value_id,
         parent_value_id,
         descriptor_value_id as root_id,
         1 as value_level
  FROM descriptor_value 
  WHERE parent_value_id IS NULL --<< you need some starting condition!

  UNION ALL

  SELECT c.descriptor_value_id,
         c.parent_value_id,
         p.root_id, --<< copy the root id to all rows
         p.value_level + 1
  FROM descriptor_value c 
   JOIN cte p ON c.parent_value_id = p.descriptor_value_id
) 
SELECT * 
FROM cte;
```

Comment: No, it doesn't give the same result. There are 326 rows in in table `descriptor_value` . Oracle V_DESC_VALUE_HIERARCH_FULL has 376 rows, your solution gives 326 rows.